# Searching a list of lists with unique keys

Tags: python

I have a list of track information from Spotify:

`track_list = [[track_id1, track_title1, track_popularity1],[track_id2, track_title2, track_popularity2]`

Each track_id is unique. Is there a way to find the entry that matches the track_id without iterating through the entire list every time?

```
def find_track(track_id, track_list):
    for track in track_list:
        if track[0] = track_id:
            return track
            break

    return('Not Found')
```

I know I could get the item I need by using a for loop, but I suspect there's a more efficient way that I've yet to discover.

Comment: You can create a hash set that contains the track IDs. Instead of looping through the whole array, you can use the `if track_id in track_id_set:` to look up the track ID.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to iterate? It's unlikely that you have that many songs, so it's quite a cheap computation and shouldn't take very long.

If for some reason efficiency is an issue, then the dict option is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient method for this purpose would be using a dictionary, where the keys are the `track_id`s and the values are the corresponding track information. This allows for constant-time lookups (`O(1)` complexity), which is significantly faster than iterating over the entire list (`O(n)` complexity).

Here's an example:

```py
def list_to_dict(track_list):
    return {track[0]: track for track in track_list}

def find_track(track_id, track_dict):
    return track_dict.get(track_id, 'Not Found')

# Example usage:
track_list = [
    ['track_id1', 'track_title1', 'track_popularity1'],
    ['track_id2', 'track_title2', 'track_popularity2']
]

track_dict = list_to_dict(track_list)
track = find_track('track_id1', track_dict)
print(track)
```